Problem of resizing and scaling
i have to make this table
My code have 2 problems, one i want (grey or dotted) line to be at scale entry 1, then entry(2,5,10) will be on one side and entry (0.01,0.05,0.1,0.2 and 0.5) on other side. My scale is not appearing like this. Secondly. the nodes are not according to this provided table
so far i have this code:
     \documentclass[11pt]{report}

     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage{multirow}
     \usepackage{pgfplots}
     \usepackage[width=200mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

     \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

      \newcommand{\errplot}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
      \begin{axis}[y=\baselineskip,
        ymax=11.4,
        ymin=0,
        axis y line*=middle,
        y axis line style=dashed,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line*=bottom]
    \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit]
        coordinates{
            (0.03,11)+-(0.86,-1.7)
            (0.02,10)+-(0.9,-0.81)
            (0.13,9)+-(0.69,-0.49)
            (0.10,8)+-(0.7,-0.1)
            (0.10,7)+-(0.72,0.88)
            (0.10,6)+-(0.7,0.04)
            (0.04,5)+-(0.68,-0.75)
            (1.53,4)+-(0.53,-1.13)
            (0.92,3)+-(0.54,0.1)
            (0.94,2)+-(0.55,-1.31)
            (0.53,1)+-(0.54,-0.3)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{table}[h!]
   \centering 
   \caption{Estimated effects of ribavirin compared with no treatment on mortality outcomes from studies.}
   \label{table:ribavirin_effects}

    \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
    \toprule
    & & Ribavirin & No Ribavirin & Odds \\ 
    Study & & Deaths/Total & Deaths/Total & Ratio (95\% CI) \\\midrule
    Ajayi,2013 & \multirow{12}{7cm}{\errplot} & 1/7 & 3/3 & 0.03(0.00 to 1.04) \\
    Asogun,2012 & & 41/148 & 12/12 & 0.02(0.00 to 0.27) \\
    Buba,2018 & & 6/19 & 22/28 & 0.13(0.03 to 0.47) \\
    Dahmane,2014 & & 8/20 & 14/16 & 0.10 (0.02 to 0.54) \\
    Lior,2019 & & 69/334 & 15/21 & 0.10 (0.04 to 0.28) \\
    Joseph,2019 & & 7/43 & 2/3 & 0.10 (0.01 to 1.22) \\
    Orji,2020 & & 4/21 & 3/3 & 0.04 (0.00 to 0.85) \\
    Price,1988 & & 12/55 & 2/13 & 1.53 (0.30 to 7.89) \\
    Samuels,2020 & & 23/38 & 5/8 & 0.92 (0.19 to 4.43) \\
    Shaffer,2014 & & 44/74 & 14/23 & 0.94 (0.36 to 2.46) \\
    Wauguier,2020 & & 29/61 & 7/11 & 0.53 (0.14 to 2.02) \\[4ex]\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}

This is what code produces for now:


Welcome. // Please add a screenshot of what your code produces so far. Thank you

@MS-SPO i've added it now

You should replace axis by semilogxaxis AND adjust the values (coordinates) accordingly, to begin with.

Nah its not working, it creates a box  around nodes instead

Did you replace in begin and end? // One feature of this community is that discussions, like you see in other places, are discouraged. So I have to stop here. // Instead of „nah-ing“ I suggest to append updates to your problem, i.e. your question.

When you post someone else's code, you should credit the author in your question and include a link. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719625/125871

sorry I'm a beginner here so i didn't know much about these things

Here are the necessary modifications:

Use semilogxaxis instead of axis. (This will also move the dashed line to 1.)
Declare your tick labels with xtick={.01,.05,.1,.2,.5,1,2,5,10}
Use log ticks with fixed point (otherwise the default is scientific notation).
To prevent tick labels from overlapping, you may want to use tick label style={font=\scriptsize}, but you might want to adjust spacing in general to get it all to fit on the page.
Set error bars with -= and +=. (The coordinates have to be calculated from the data. I did it quickly so don't trust my arithmetic.)
Since you can't have the lower error going to 0 on a logarithmic axis, I set the lower limit to .002
\\[.68ex] to adjust the spacing at the bottom.


\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[width=200mm, top=35mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\errplot}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            y=\baselineskip,
            ymax=11.4,
            ymin=0,
            axis y line*=middle,
            y axis line style=dashed,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick={.01,.05,.1,.2,.5,1,2,5,10},
            log ticks with fixed point,
            tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
            axis x line*=bottom]
        \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit]
            coordinates{
                (0.03,11)-=(0.028,0)+=(1.01,0)
                (0.02,10)-=(0.018,0)+=(0.25,0)
                (0.13,9)-=(0.10,0)+=(0.34,0)
                (0.10,8)-=(0.08,0)+=(0.44,0)
                (0.10,7)-=(0.06,0)+=(0.18,0)
                (0.10,6)-=(0.09,0)+=(1.12,0)
                (0.04,5)-=(0.038,0)+=(0.81,0)
                (1.53,4)-=(1.23,0)+=(6.36,0)
                (0.92,3)-=(0.73,0)+=(3.51,0)
                (0.94,2)-=(0.58,0)+=(1.52,0)
                (0.53,1)-=(0.39,0)+=(1.49,0)
            };
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\caption{Estimated effects of ribavirin compared with no treatment on mortality outcomes from studies.}
\label{table:ribavirin_effects}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
\toprule
& & Ribavirin & No Ribavirin & Odds \\ 
Study & & Deaths/Total & Deaths/Total & Ratio (95\% CI) \\\midrule
Ajayi,2013 & \multirow{12}{6.5cm}{\errplot} & 1/7 & 3/3 & 0.03(0.00 to 1.04) \\
Asogun,2012 & & 41/148 & 12/12 & 0.02(0.00 to 0.27) \\
Buba,2018 & & 6/19 & 22/28 & 0.13(0.03 to 0.47) \\
Dahmane,2014 & & 8/20 & 14/16 & 0.10 (0.02 to 0.54) \\
Lior,2019 & & 69/334 & 15/21 & 0.10 (0.04 to 0.28) \\
Joseph,2019 & & 7/43 & 2/3 & 0.10 (0.01 to 1.22) \\
Orji,2020 & & 4/21 & 3/3 & 0.04 (0.00 to 0.85) \\
Price,1988 & & 12/55 & 2/13 & 1.53 (0.30 to 7.89) \\
Samuels,2020 & & 23/38 & 5/8 & 0.92 (0.19 to 4.43) \\
Shaffer,2014 & & 44/74 & 14/23 & 0.94 (0.36 to 2.46) \\
Wauguier,2020 & & 29/61 & 7/11 & 0.53 (0.14 to 2.02) \\[.68ex]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

